# The 'mutual' and the 'self' in terms of the 'conjugacy' of Euclidean and Minkowski Weyl fermions

Tags: mathematical-physics, representation-theory, spinors, wick-rotation, clifford-algebra

Euclidean and Minkowski fermions are shown in the Table of Wikipedia. (see the bottom https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor#Summary_in_low_dimensions)

> My question is that what does the *conjugacy* mean  here precisely? What do the *mutual* and the *self* mean in terms of the *conjugacy*?

See Wikipedia page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let the spacetime metric have signature $(s,t)$.

1. *Mutual conjugated* means that the left and right Weyl representations are each other's complex conjugate [complex representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_representation). This happens if $s-t~=~2\mod 4$.
2. *Self-conjugated* means that the left and right Weyl representations are ([pseudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_representation)) [real representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_representation). This happens if $s-t~=~0\mod 4$.

(Weyl representations only exist in even spacetime dimensions $s+t~=~0\mod 2$.)